# Javascript RegExp - how do I match for a word, but not if another word is also present?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am testing a string against a series of regular expressions. Most of these are simple - often just testing if a single word appears in the string like so

```
var str = 'Blah blah foo blah';

var my_array = [
    {
        test: 'foo',
        name: 'foo_ame'
    },
    {
        test: 'bar',
        name: 'bar_name'
    }
]

for (var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
    if (new RegExp(my_array[i].test).test(str)) {
        console.log(my_array[i].name); // foo_name
    }
}
```

I have one case where I want to match if the string contains 'qux' and not 'foo', eg

```
for 'blah foo blah'     returns foo_name
for 'blah foo qux blah' returns qux_name (only)
```

It's only really necessary for this one case out of about 30 so I'd rather not rewrite the loop if I can avoid it. Is it something I can match for with regular expressions?

Comment: Sorry about my javascript ignorance, but on Perl I would just use this: `my $test = "blah qux blah";
if ($test =~ m/ qux / && !($test =~ m/ foo /))
{
 print("Has qux and not foo\n");
}`

Comment: @m0skit0, oh Perl users, everything is regex isnt it lol. Honestly you could probably get by in this case without using regex. I would probably just use indexOf twice. `if($test.indexOf("foo") == -1 && $test.indexOf("qux") >= 0)....`. Seems like they will be short strings.

Comment: Perl and regex ftw! :)
He asked about regex, and anyway your solution performs the same searches over the string. And btw you didn't consider those as words as stated on the original question ;)

Comment: @Matt, your indexOf solution doesn't work as you need to check for word boundaries to be sure its not part of a larger word.

Comment: @a'r ahhh, touche. You are right.

Comment: @Matt, you could of course split the string into an array and search it, but I suspect the regex method would be more concise and readable.

Comment: @a'r You are of course right, but note that liam has the same issue with his original code!

Comment: @a'r you raise an excellent point, but I can't be entirely sure that the strings I'm searching for will be space-separated.

Comment: @liam, your original question mentioned 'words', which implies testing for word boundaries, but if you don't need them, then leave them out.

Comment: @a'r that's what I just said on my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to do this within one regular expression is to use a lookaround, but it'd be quite bulky because you'd want to catch instances where "foo" precedes *or* follows "qux". E.g.

```
/^(?:(?!foo).)*qux(?:(?!foo).)*$/
```

I would suggest changing the way you test the strings so you can have a positive regex and a negative regex -- i.e. one the string must pass against and one the string must fail against.

Comment: A solution that worked and sound advice, thank you. To anyone else interested, this solution can be extended to more than one negated word by piping them together:
`/^(?:(?!foo|bar).)*qux(?:(?!foo|bar).)*$/`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for a "negative lookbehind"
([see this very good online help](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) - unfortunately, they say javascript does not support "lookbehinds")

eg. 
`(?<!a)b` matches a "b" that is not preceded by an "a"

so in your case:

```
(?<!foo )qux //don't forget the space after foo
```

Comment: JavaScript supports lookaheads, but not lookbehinds.

Comment: @J-P: thx, I thought, if lookbeinds are not supported then probably lookaheads too - I shouldn't have guessed (edited the answer)